# selecting the same column multiple time from 1 table via 3 inner joins

Tags: mysql

Working on a medical database.
We have a prescriptions table, a diagnosis table and an items table (every single item, not just meds).

In the diagnosis table, is a whole set of columns called med# (currently 13, may increase) that lists all the various medication the patient is prescribed. The names of the medicine are stored on the items table (because multi-lingual) To retrieve the name of medication 1~13, I'm using the below query.

It works, but I imagine that it's probably not very efficient.
Is there a better way to rewrite this?
Or maybe even redesign the database?
It's still early stages and the DB design isn't locked down yet.

```
select d.name_en, e.name_en
from
    diag a
    inner join
pres c
    on a.med1 = c.id
    inner join
pres b
    on a.med2 = b.id
    inner join
items d
    on b.id = d.id
    inner join
items e
    on c.id = e.id
where a.id = 1
```

Comment: If the number of columns can increase, then there is a problem with your design.

Comment: Does the diagnosis table hold patient information?

Comment: @Strawberry, I meant that it may increase from what we have now, but will be locked down once the design is finalised.

Comment: @Andrew no. There is a separate patient db which is also joined to the diag table.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a table that holds patient information and another table that holds medication information. This will allow the number of medications to grow without table redesign.

In the medication information table, there should be a column to reference the item in the items table and a column to reference the patient in the patient information table. This will be the primary key of your medication information table.

Comment: More likely, given that one medication can be prescribed to many patients and one patient can be prescribed many medications, you would want a table for patients, a table for medications, and a table that relates one to the other, including the dosage.

Comment: Yes. That's what I suggested. The items table holds the medications according to the47thsen's question. I guess I could've been more explicit and referred to 'medication information' as 'patient medication information'. Additionally, the columns that I suggested aren't expected to be the only columns in the table. Information such as dosage should definitely be included. I didn't want to spend too much time designing the table since I don't know the requirements of the47thsen's database.

Comment: I have changed it so now there is a patients table, a diagnosis table a medication table, and an intermediary/pivot table called prescriptions linking diagnosis and medication together.

So prescriptions will have these columns, id, diag_id, med_id, dose with each medication taking up a new row instead of another column. I had thought it would be neater to have just 1 diagnosis row with medications stored as columns but this may be easier to manage maybe?

I'm still quite new at this kind of thing.

Comment: A normalized design would have a table with a separate row for each medication. Don't confuse data *storage* with data *retrieval* and *display*.